# How to extract info from package in R and use in function?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, nested-loops

I apologize for the vague question title. What I want to do is run a regression in R using geeglm from the geepack R package, then use information from that to calculate a quasilikelihood information criteria (QIC; Pan 2001). I can do this fairly easily for single models but I would like to write a general function that can do this for a variety of different types of models. I guess my real question is whether there is a better alternative than having a long series of nested ifelse statements?

Here's my current code:

```
library(geepack)
data(dietox) #data from the geepack package
# Run gee regression
dietox$Cu <- as.factor(dietox$Cu)
mf <- formula(Weight ~ Cu * (Time + I(Time^2) + I(Time^3)))
gee1 <- geeglm(mf, data = dietox, id = Pig, family = gaussian, corstr = "ar1")
```

Then I can run a function to calculate the quasilikelihood:

```
QlogLik.normal <- function(model.R) {
  library(MASS)
  mu.R <- model.R$fitted.values
  y <- model.R$y
  # Quasi Likelihood for Normal
  quasi.R <- sum(((y - mu.R)^2)/-2)
  quasi.R
  }
```

However, I would like to write a function that is more general because the quasilikelihood function is different for every distribution. The above function would work for gee1 because it had a gaussian (normal) distribution. If I wanted to generalize it for a variety of distributions I could use a series of nested ifelse statements (below), but I don't know if this is the best way to do this. Does anyone have other options or a better solution? This just doesn't seem very elegant to say the least (clearly I don't have much programming or R experience).

```
QlogLik <- function(model.R) {
  library(MASS)
  mu.R <- model.R$fitted.values
  y <- model.R$y
  ifelse(model.R$modelInfo$variance == "poisson",
     # Quasi Likelihood for Poisson
     quasi.R <- sum((y*log(mu.R)) - mu.R),
     ifelse(model.R$modelInfo$variance == "gaussian",
       # Quasi Likelihood for Normal
       quasi.R <- sum(((y - mu.R)^2)/-2),
       ifelse(model.R$modelInfo$variance == "binomial",
         # Quasilikelihood for Binomial
         quasi.R <- sum(y*log(mu.R/(1 - mu.R)) + log(1 - mu.R)),
         quasi.R <- "Error: distribution not recognized")))
  quasi.R
  }
```

In this example, I used the model output from geeglm to extract the type of distribution used to model the variance

```
 model.R$modelInfo$variance
```

but there may be other ways to determine what distribution was used in the geeglm model. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ifelse` is not appropriate here imho since the logical condition is not a vector, better use `if() else` instead, or `switch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to rewrite your function like this:

```
QlogLik <- function(model.R) {
  library(MASS)
  mu.R <- model.R$fitted.values
  y <- model.R$y
  type <- family(model.R)$family
  switch(type,
         poisson = sum((y*log(mu.R)) - mu.R),
         gaussian = sum(((y - mu.R)^2)/-2),
         binomial = sum(y*log(mu.R/(1 - mu.R)) + log(1 - mu.R)),
         stop("Error: distribution not recognized"))
}
```

As @baptise points out, `switch` useful in these cases. You use `family(model.R)$family` to automatically detect what family type should be used with `switch`.

Also, if your commands for what to do in different cases run beyond one line, you can wrap the lines with curly brackets (`{ do something here }`) instead.

```
switch(type,
       type1 = { something <- do(this)
                 thisis(something) },
       type2 = do(that))
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `model.R$family$family` which gives the type of distribution used to model the variance, but so far I didn't know if you could eliminate those `ifelse` statements. The `quasi.R` in your code differs among different distributions, so you have to define each of them separately.

BTW, it is a good question and thanks for posting it: I had similar situations in the past, and hope to get some advice on how to write the codes more efficiently.